reactjs/socket.io wrong socket returned on connection
I'm working on a chat app with reactjs/socket.io but I've been struggling to fix this bug for days now.
Server code:
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected`);

    socket.once('initializeUser', name => {
        socket.user = name
        onlineUsers.push(socket.user);
        console.log(onlineUsers)
    });
}

Client code:
socket.once('connect', () => {
    setConnected(true);
    socket.emit('initializeUser', auth.user);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected`);
});

The auth.user value is variable stored in the context api, which provides for my whole project. The value is set during login and emptied on logout.
Basically, my problem scenario goes:
admin1 logs in -> admin1 starts a socket connection -> admin1 logs out
At this point the console should just look something like:
User vWihsgstbBO_ca95AAA9 connected
[ 'admin1' ]
User vWihsgstbBO_ca95AAA9 disconnected

Then admin2 logs in (the same client instance) -> admin2 starts a socket connection. What I'm expecting is [admin2] but instead what I get is:
User k-HoV1aZt9JdKF39AAA_ connected
[ 'admin1' ]

Then when I just reload the page, it fixes itself to the correct output of:
[ 'admin2' ]

I've verified on the client side that when the socket is emitting initializeUser, the correct auth.user value is being passed in. However, when the server receives this emit, a different name is displayed. Any help would be appreciated!
